# PIServer network boot

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+

When i boot a raspberry pi model 3b+ from the piserver running on debian stretch x86 i get the follow error :

> ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing : VFS : unable to mount root fs on
>   unknow-block(2,0)

and it doesnt go any further.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

I've followed the instructions here : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/network-boot-raspberry-pi-without-microsd/.

Comment: `debian stretch x86` - the raspberry pi is an ARM chip - you've loaded debian for intel/amd chips - solution: use raspbian

Comment: I've installed raspbian on a virtual machine and then installed piserver on that. I did it that so we would have plenty of harddrive space and for backup reasons.  The client machines that get the operating from the x86 server raspbian over the network run the standard arm based raspbian.  Does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You write you are using a Raspberry Pi **version 3B**. Network booting is only supported by a Raspberry Pi **version 3B+**. Note the plus sign. The plus version is mainly released because it has improved boot options like stable USB boot and additional network boot. You have to use a RPi 3B+ for network booting.

Comment: apologies, just checked and the client is the 3b version of the raspberry pi.  I've just updated the original post.  Any ideas what could be causing it.

Comment: @resolver101 That is what I wrote: the 3b version does not work.

Comment: Thanks. 3b+ is the pi I am using. I did update the question. Just didn't type the plus on here. Apologies.